# How to Integrate Command prompt/Terminal in a Windows application?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, console-application

Many programs like VS Code have a built-in terminal window that allows user to execute commands just as if they were working in command prompt or powershell. I'm working on adding similar functionality to my winforms application, and allow user to create multiple terminal windows.

I tried to do this by launching cmd.exe as a hidden process and redirecting stdin/stdout. But running into issues with synchronizing stdout & stderr output. There is no sure way of knowing where to insert stderr output in the stdout output and I often end up with out-of-place error messages - sometimes in-between stdout lines. If I use same handle for stderr/stdout, then output is synchronized correclty, however, I can't tell whether its error text so can't color code it.

Is my fundamental approach of running cmd.exe as a hidden process correct? If yes, then how do I merge output from stdout/stderr?

Comment: you can pass the same handle for both stdout/stderr. anyway *sometimes in-between stdout lines* is trange, because cmd, how i know, do all output from single thread, so it serialized

Comment: I think with [Windows 10 Pseudo Console](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/) ([ConPTY API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creating-a-pseudoconsole-session)), you don't need such tricks as hidden "cmd.exe" process anymore.

Comment: @RbMm if I pass same handle for both then I wont be able to identify and color-code the error output. Are you sure about single threaded ouput from console?

Comment: not sure are really need use different colors for stderr and stdout output. *Are you sure about single threaded ouput from console?* - yes. in which case you got *in-between stdout lines.* ?

Comment: @zett42 - but even if use *CreatePseudoConsole* - anyway hiden cmd.exe need exec - look for code example in page from your link. *commandline = L"c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";* or [*here*](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/master/samples/ConPTY/EchoCon/EchoCon/EchoCon.cpp#L45)

Comment: @RbMm My misconception. Of course, you need to run cmd or powershell when you want to execute commands. As I see it, ConPTY advantage is that you don't need to rely on stdin/stdout redirection. E. g. console app may call `WriteConsoleOutput` which can't be captured by normal redirection (previously required polling of console output buffer). With ConPTY you can capture such output by reading pipe of pseudo console.

Comment: I've updated my question a bit. The issue might be WinForms which could be causing synchronizing issues between stdout/stderr.

Comment: @RbMm In the blog post, about halfway down the page he writes about `WriteConsoleOutput`: _"When a legacy Command-Line app uses a Console API like WriteConsoleOutput(...), the specified text is written to the attached ConHost’s Output Buffer. Periodically, ConHost renders changed areas of the Output Buffer as text/VT which is sent via stdout back to the Console."_

Comment: @zett42 - yes, i mistake. `CreatePseudoConsole` really exec *conhost.exe* with special command line, which instead create console window, write data to *hOutput* and read data from *hInput*. like we create child with redirected handles. if we then run some console program with `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PSEUDOCONSOLE` handle - it attached to this special *conhost.exe*. as result yes - all console output (including `WriteConsoleOutput`) finally will be written to *hOutput*

Comment: MS has a C# WPF sample for using ConPTY: [GUIConsole](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/tree/master/samples/ConPTY/GUIConsole).

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand, you may be able to do like below.

C++:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
void main()
{
    char cmd[] = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    CreateProcessA(cmd, NULL, NULL, NULL, FLASE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
}
```

with no `dwCreationFlags` flag, The child process `cmd.exe` and the parent process share the same console.

Comment: I've clarified my question a bit more. Basically, I need to display output in a winforms window and user can open multiple windows. Using console will limit me to just one console window.